# carbon.xml HostName in a Clustered Environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

If I'm using WSO2EI on a Clustered Environment what am I going to write on this tag In the **carbon.xml** file on each node?:

```
<HostName>ei.wso2.com</HostName>
```

Is it a **Unique** HostName like: "ei1.wso2.com" for Node 1 and "ei2.wso2.com" for Node 2. Or a **Shared** HostName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HostName parameter is explained with a comment as bellow in the carbon.xml file.

> Host name or IP address of the machine hosting this server    e.g.
>   www.wso2.org, 192.168.1.10
>   This will become part of the End
>   Point Reference of the services deployed on this server instance.

To further explain, let's say you are setting up WSO2EI instance in a VM, where the hostname of VM is "abc.xyz.com", you can set the hostname as "abc.xyz.com". If you have a multi-node cluster which is distributed across different VMs, the hostname of each WSO2EI instance can be configured to related VMs hostname.